# how to swap one line with another in c++

Tags: c++

My objective is to search for a particular line in the file, modify it and save the file in c++. i am trying to do this via fstream such as shown below

```
fstream someFile(fileName, filestream::ate | filestream::in |  filestream::out);
streampos endPos =  someFile.tellg();
streampos.seekg(0, fstream::beg);
string line;
while(someFile && someFile.tellg() != endPos  && getline(somefile, line))
{
  if(correctLine(line))
  {
    modifyLine(line);
   //save Line.. How do i do this?
  }
 }
```

My question is how do i replace the line obtained from getline function with the modified line?
Also, after getline, would the file position will be at the start of the current line or would it be placed at the end of the current line?

Comment: Replacing lines in a file has been covered many, many times. What research have you performed?

Comment: Strong suggestion: consider using *two* streams: one for reading, the other for writing.

Comment: i looked at c++ documentation for fstream

Comment: Using memory mapped files could be more efficient, posting a solution based on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@harper is correct, that you can't just alter the file unless the new line is the same size as the old line. What you can do is read into a [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) and then write the `stringstream` back out, completely overwriting the file with the new version.

Here's an example of replacing a single line from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175062/using-fstream-write/). In your case, you'd just need to do something more complicated than the `line == target`, but it's basically the same.

Be warned that this reads the entire file into memory, so it will use a lot of memory if the file is large.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* Accept filename, target and replacement string from arguments for a more
       useful example. */
    if (argc != 4) {
        std::cout << argv[0] << " [file] [target string] [replacement string]\n"
            << "    Replaces [target string] with [replacement string] in [file]" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Give these arguments more meaningful names. */
    const char* filename = argv[1];
    std::string target(argv[2]);
    std::string replacement(argv[3]);

    /* Read the whole file into a stringstream. */
    std::stringstream buffer;
    std::fstream file(filename, std::fstream::in);
    for (std::string line; getline(file, line); ) {
        /* Do the replacement while we read the file. */
        if (line == target) {
            buffer << replacement;
        } else {
            buffer << line;
        }
        buffer << std::endl;
    }
    file.close();

    /* Write the whole stringstream back to the file */
    file.open(filename, std::fstream::out);
    file << buffer.str();
    file.close();
}
```

Note: If you want to be clever, you could probably leave the file alone until you find the line to replace, and then only replace the content after that..

Comment: Even cleverer seems to be to leave the part of the file you don't need to modify untouched on disk. I believe memory-mapped files can deliver this (see my answer, which also allows replacements of arbitrary lengths)

Answer (score 4):

A line is a thing with an unknown length. Therefore you can't just replace it. You will need to have a source file stream and a destination file stream. While copying the stream you can replace any line you want.

Comment: I dont want to copy source file to destination file. Rather, i want to make a modification to file and save the modification back.

Comment: getline gives a string back and i can call length() on the string to determine the line length

Comment: @Jimm - you will effectively do what you don't want to, there is no other way, even if you rewrite the file it will create a new version of it, you cannot do that kind of data inserts into files.

Comment: @Jimm You can only do that if the length of the modified line is the same as the length of the unmodified line. Accept the fact that you will almost certainly need to write the entire contents back out to a file.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious in my case, before and after line sizes are the same. How do i replace in this casE?

Comment: @Jimm See Brendan's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17371222/845568) for how to do it when the lengths are the same.

Answer (score 3):

**If the two lines are exactly the same length**, you can just go back to the position to start with and write the line out again. I think the code would look something like this:

```
// we need to go back 1 extra to take the line break into account
someFile.seekp(-line.size() - 1, std::ios_base::cur);
someFile.write(line.data(), line.size());
```

Comment: I wouldn't trust any `operator<<` to push the correct number of bytes, even the ones that take `const char*` or `std::string`.  I would use `someFile.write()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use memory mapped files, you might reduce the actual disk access (write accesses). If the matching line is in 'late' blocks, you can avoid (re)writing any of the preceding blocks.

The following code

- uses boost in order not be platform dependent
- allows for replacements that are shorter as well as longer than the matched target line
- resizes the file in-place
- demonstrates looking for lines by regex
- is pretty well tested (on linux), prior to posting it here

See the inline comments for rationale. Code:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost;

const auto MAX_INCREASE = 1024; // allow 1 kilobyte room to grow

void process(
        filesystem::path const& spec, 
        std::string const& pattern, 
        std::string const& replace)
{
    // get current size of file on disk
    auto const cur_size = file_size(spec);

    // map, with MAX_INCREASE room to spare
    iostreams::mapped_file mmap(
            spec.native(), 
            iostreams::mapped_file::readwrite, 
            cur_size+MAX_INCREASE);

    // find the line matching 'pattern'
    char *bof = mmap.data();
    char *eof = bof + cur_size; // don't read beyond cur_size!

    regex re(pattern);
    match_results<char*> match;

    if (regex_search(bof, eof, match, re))
    {
        // replace the matched contents!
        auto b = match[0].first,
             e = match[0].second;
        std::cout << "Matching line: '" << std::string(b, e) << "'\n";

        // figure out whether we need to grow/shrink
        auto delta = (b + replace.size()) - e;
        std::cout << "Delta: " << delta << "\n";

        if (delta < 0)
        {
            // shrinking
            std::copy(replace.begin(), replace.end(), b); // replacement
            std::copy(e, eof, e + delta);                 // shift back
            resize_file(filesystem::path(spec), cur_size + delta);
        }
        else if (delta < MAX_INCREASE)
        {
            // growing
            resize_file(filesystem::path(spec), cur_size + delta);
            std::copy_backward(b, eof, eof + delta);      // shift onwards
            std::copy(replace.begin(), replace.end(), b); // insert replacement
        }
        else
        {
            // error handling (MAX_INCREASE exceeded)
        }
    }
    // TODO error handling (no match)?
}

int main()
{
    process("input.txt", "^int .*?$", "void foo()\n// mmap was here");
    //process("input.txt", "^int .*?$", "");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First place the put pointer to required position from you want to start the replace.
fileobj.seekp(fileobj.tellp(-lengthOfLine,ios::cur),ios::beg);

then simply write the line.

Fileobj << linestring;

if lines have different sizes , check out brendan's answer

Comment: Do that and chances are you will corrupt your file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how would the above suggestion corrupt file?

Comment: Because you're seeking to the current location instead of the beginning of the **line**.